# Using the value present in String type variable as tablename

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic

In my C# code, I am retrieving data from database using stored procedure and I am creating the tables(I mean GUI tables in .Net) dynamically and adding the rows and columns to that table dynamically. I have 4 tables & 4 respective Stored procedures. Instead of writing one method for each table, I want to write a single method which will be called from four methods(4 button click methods) because only stored procedure name & table name will be changed and everything else remains same. I am trying to use the below code.

```
    public String StoredProcName; //Values will be "GetFirstYearCSESubjects","GetSecondYearCSESubjects","GetThirdYearCSESubjects","GetFourthYearCSESubjects"
    public String TableName; //Values will be "tblCSE1","tblCSE2","tblCSE3","tblCSE4"
    protected void tabCSE1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CSEView.ActiveViewIndex = 0;      
        StoredProcName = "GetFirstYearCSESubjects";
        TableName = "tblCSE1";
        phCSE1.Controls.Clear();
        Table tblCSE1 = new Table();
        phCSE1.Controls.Add(tblCSE1);
        addCurriculumData(StoredProcName, TableName);
        ViewState["dynamictable"] = true;
    }

    public void addCurriculumData(String StoredProcName,String TableName)
    {
        String strCon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConStr"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(strCon);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(StoredProcName, sqlCon);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        sqlCon.Open();
        SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (rdr.HasRows)
        {
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                TableRow tr = new TableRow();
                for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++)
                {
                    TableCell tc = new TableCell();
                    Label lbl = new Label();
                    lbl.Text = rdr["Subject"].ToString();
                    tc.Controls.Add(lbl);
                    tr.Cells.Add(tc);
                }
                TableName.Rows.Add(tr);***//How should I write this statement???***
            }
        }
        else
            lblMessage.Text = "No Data found";
    }
```

I am not sure how am I supposed to write the statement `TableName.Rows.Add(tr)`. As TableName is a string, it cant have Rows and therefore it throws error. So I should mention the value at TableName instead of TableName. How should I do that? Can I use the concept of pointers? I am not quite sure of pointers. Or is there another way to do that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you kidding?? Have you tried to instantiate an object of type 'Table' and add rows to it instead of adding them to a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass Table (not string) to the method and interact with the Table

```
public void addCurriculumData(String StoredProcName,Table table)
```